# How do decorators work when arguments are passed to them

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am just trying to get familiar with decorators in Python, but as a newbie to the language I cannot understand why I get this below:

My code for decorators with argument:

```
def decorator_with_argument(fun_name):  
    def decorator_func(func):
        '''decorator function which will provide additional functionality to my original function'''
        print("Inside decorator")
        def wrapper_func(*args,**kwargs):
            print("Inside wrapper")
            print("Calling function {} with parameters {} {}".format(fun_name, *args, **kwargs))
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator_func

@decorator_with_argument("Addition")
def addition_func(a,b):
    print(a+b)

@decorator_with_argument("Subtraction")
def subtraction_func(a,b):
    print(a-b)

addition_func(10,15)
subtraction_func(25,10)
```

Output:

```
Inside decorator
Inside decorator
Inside wrapper
Calling function Addition with parameters 10 15
25
Inside wrapper
Calling function Subtraction with parameters 25 10
15
```

Can someone explain me why I get "Inside decorator" twice?

Answer (score 0):

The decorator runs twice because you are decorating two functions. The decorator runs when each decorated function is being defined, as Python parses and internally byte-compiles the program.

Whether the decorator accepts arguments is immaterial; this is what decorators are used for - running a function on another function as it is being defined.